# Where can I find the AI persona core?

Tags: rimworld

I am trying to build a spaceship, however it seems I need a Ship Computer Core in order to finish building the spaceship and the Ship Computer Core requires an item called an AI persona core in order to build it:

[image]

Where can I find the AI persona core?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The AI persona core is acquired after a rare event where a ship crashes in your world, you then have to destroy the shipwreck (by attacking it), but beware of its defenses. You then research "Ship computer core" and you're there.

Comment: I think I saw it on market. Can't we buy it?

Comment: Yes, you can buy it. They are fairly expensive, however.

Answer (score 2):

You can call an allied faction via the comms console and ask them for the location of an AI persona core.